# Read 2 bytes as integer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a buffer containing the following:

`04 01 0c ea c0 a8 00 01 00`

The 3rd and 4th bytes (`0x0c` `0xea`) form a port number (3306), but how can I take these bytes and transform them into this integer (3306)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want `buf.readInt16LE()`.

http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint16le_offset_noassert

Comment: It returns 5620, but `buf.readInt16BE()` returns correctly. Thanks

Comment: I always mix up my endianess.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: @Drahcir You mean -5620. Why do you by the way have a big endian number in the first place? Little endian is pretty much industry standard by now, you generally shouldn't use big endian unless you are implementing a standard that requires so. Also the correct command is `readUInt16BE`, as `readInt16BE` will return negative values for half the port range.

Comment: @eBusiness I'm implementing a [SOCKS4 Proxy](http://www.openssh.com/txt/socks4.protocol), so the standard is predefined. Those bytes are the CONNECT request from the client. Valid point about Uint vs Int.